# How do I get the real config value in Git?

Tags: git

It seems that `git config` only returns value that I explicitly set and doesn't aware of the default values. For example when I run `git config commit.status` it outputs nothing.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config helps but doesn't list all of the default values.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible.  Perhaps someone more familiar with the git source code will correct me, but I think that the default values are typically hard-coded in the source files and overridden by the config variables.  For example, the default for `gc.pruneExpire` is defined [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/gc.c#L29]) and potentially overridden [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/gc.c#L59) when the configuration is checked.  I don't think there's any mechanism for `git config` to get at that default value.

Comment: That's right. The `git config` man page, however, will note the defaults for most options.

Comment: See an extended discussion of the problem getting default values in [this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33720449/2392683).