# How can I get list of all default git config options

Tags: git

I need a way to get a list of all default options that could be inserted into `.gitconfig` file

I don't mean going through all man pages :) more generic solution that could work for future versions would be most appreciated+

update: the closest I get to actual results is `grep -r 'strcmp(var, ' ~/git-cource-code`

update2:
after 4 years (since version 2.19) git has the possibility of listing all possible config options (sadly without defaults :( )

Comment: You'd have to check out Git sourcecode. Have you?

Comment: I can `grep -r 'git config --get' .` in git source code but it's not great, not perfect and requires a lot of later work

Comment: not great, sure, but not sure you have the choice... Ask on the Git ML to be sure

Comment: It seems there is no known way of getting the default values. The answer to a similar question might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991215/how-do-i-get-the-real-config-value-in-git

Answer (score 3):

try `git config --list` for local repository or `git config --global --list` for global settings and `git config --system --list` for system wide settings

Also helpful info about GIT options http://nikedlab.com/tutorial/git-setup.html

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html
If you see not in list option it means this option is not setted

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't give you the default values, but you can list all the possibilities:

`git help --config`

To see valid values (super helpful for enums like `blame.coloring` for example)

`man git-config`

Has most of them.  You can search for the one you want in less, or even just grep the output:

`grep -A 10 -P blame.coloring <(man git-config)`