# How to obtain the effective git-config values and their source?

Tags: git, git-config

I know [`git-config` doesn't know all possible default values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33720449/321973), but is there any way to see not only which config values apply to the current repo but also *which* config (local, global, system) is responsible?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Sure, just

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

Comment: only as of git 2.8

Comment: This won't include values set from supported environment variables, like `EMAIL` (for `user.email`).

Comment: @void.pointer Good point, though not too surprising since that could be overridden per command anyway... The dupe-question https://stackoverflow.com/q/17756753/321973 also doesn't mention this I think... Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: This doesn't show the full picture (i.e. it doesn't include defaults/unset values), doesn't show the effective configuration in its entirety.