# What config values are actually being used by git?

Tags: git

To see all of the git config values you can use:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

My question is this.   If `core.autocrlf` shows up multiple times (some `true` and some `false`).  Which value is actually being used?  Is there a command that shows you the "effective" git config value being used for every config value?

Searching I found:

- [How to obtain the effective git-config values and their source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132520/how-to-obtain-the-effective-git-config-values-and-their-source) - I thought this would be the answer to my question but it just shows how to use `git config --list --show-origin`.  This points to
- [Where do the settings in my Git configuration come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756753/where-do-the-settings-in-my-git-configuration-come-from) - This nicely explains how there are multiple git locations but it doesn't say what the effective value is.

NOTE: It appears by experimentation that

```
git config --get core.autocrlf
```

Gives me the effective value (for the one config property `core.autocrlf`).

**Is there a command that gives you the effective value for all config properties?**

Answer (score 1):

If you go with `git config --list`, you will get all settings, global, local. For specific git project you can use

```
git config -l --local --show-origin
```

The same way with `--global` you could see your global settings (applied if you are not modifing any configuration for the project).

The 'magic' behind this is that there is a global settings that can be overriden by a local project settings. The most common thing is to set your email. Git wants you to set it globally first

```
git config --global user.email john@example.com
```

Then you will start a new project and this global configuration is automatically inhereted. But now you have the possibility to change it

```
git config user.email peter@example.com
```

and now you will see two user.email rows while `git confg --list`. The global will be the first one and the second one will be local, because it overrides the first value. Using `--local` git will retrieve only the final data for your local project.

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't appear to show the **effective values of all of the settings** .  I ran `git config --list  --show-origin | grep auto` and got `file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig core.autocrlf=true`, but when I added the `--local` option, the value for `core.autocrlf` did not appear.  So `--local` seems to show my local overrides but not **all of the options** that have been set.

Comment: You are right, the `--local` takes only the values from repository, I thought it takes all, my bad. It took me a while, but I haven't found a built in solution, so you probably will have to write a shell script. First to get an array with `--global`, then `--local` and if the global line key exists in local, then override it. Also look at the `--system` settings and what priority it has.