# How to exclude a color from git's graphColors?

Tags: git, git-log, konsole

I'd like to customize the colors used in `git log --graph` via [`log.graphColors`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html). Basically, I need to keep the default colors, just exclude the blue color as it's barely readable in my terminal. What would be the cleanest way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is the original colorset:

```
red,green,yellow,blue,magenta,cyan,bold red,bold green,bold yellow,bold blue,bold magenta,bold cyan
```

You can skip the blue and set this in your `.gitconfig` file:

```
[log]
    graphColors = red,green,yellow,magenta,cyan,bold red,bold green,bold yellow,bold magenta,bold cyan
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is currently no way of getting the **default** values of `git` configuration variables (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33720449/1988796) for more information and links).

A thing you could check/try:

- Is your terminal changing the colors?

  It could be that the `ANSI color escape sequence` blue does not appear blue in your terminal. An easy way to check this might be to use

  ```
  # set current branch color to blue
  git config color.branch.current blue
  git branch
  # check the color of the branch and then reset it
  git config --unset color.branch.current
  # or to try colors more genaral (note the quotes)
  git config color.branch.current '[<attribute>,..] <color> <color>'
  git branch
  ```

  `<attribute>`s available `bold, dim, ul, blink, reverse, italic, and strike`. Special note here about `bold` as for example iTerm2 uses the color specified in the **bright** column (in the colors settings tab) for `bold` colors

  `<color>`s available `normal, black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan and white`. First is foreground-, second is background-color

  **If yes:** Find out how to change the color in your terminal
- Set the option with a list of colors you like (omitting blue) and enjoy

I hope that you found a satisfying solution, or at least something interesting to read.

Answer (score 1):

In Konsole, you can simply adjust the color scheme in your profile to make the blue color slightly lighter. Go to Settings > Edit current profile... > Appearance. Once there, select your color theme and edit it to your preference.

This will fix the issue not only for `git`, but any other terminal app that uses colored output.