# How to colorize branch name in output of "git checkout"?

Tags: git, git-config

How to colorize the branch name (shown in bold below) in the output of `git checkout`?

```
(base) dollaween $ git checkout develop
Switched to branch 'develop'
```

Comment: You could probably do something with `sed` where you surround the single quotes in the escape characters that set terminal colors.  But you would have to do that every time you `git checkout`, or write a function/script that wraps `git checkout`.

Answer (score 3):

Color settings for different commands are controlled by the config variables

```
color.<command>.<slot>
```

You can see all available config variables with the command `git help -c` (see [git config: list all variables and their default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720397/git-config-list-all-variables-and-their-default-values)). If there is no variable called `color.checkout.…` then I think this is not possible.

The closest replacement I could think of would be to colorize the branch name in the output of `git status`.

For example:

```
$ git config color.status.branch red
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
[…]
```

The bold part would now be red.

Comment: _then I think this is not possible._ - If I understand C code correct, `git checkout` does not support what the OP wants: https://github.com/git/git/blob/e31aba42fb12bdeb0f850829e008e1e3f43af500/builtin/checkout.c#L927 as it seems to print the branch name only.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work(
This work for `git status`, but not for `git checkout`

Comment: That's what I wrote. Unfortunately, I don't know another way.